# How to set Proxy Settings while invoking Web Service through proxy server from Axis2 Web Service Client?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Not able to set the Proxy Settings in Axis2 Web Service Client.

Comment: we require more that that.. please post some code which you've tried or any exception(s) you have recieved..

not sure if you've looked at http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#auth

Answer (score 3):

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(); // build your service client here

Options options = new Options();

HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
proxyProperties.setDomain("");
proxyProperties.setProxyName("");
proxyProperties.setProxyPort(8000);
proxyProperties.setUserName("");
proxyProperties.setPassWord("");

options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
client.setOptions(options);
```

Thanks...